# Asymptotic representation of the function $\frac{a+bx^2\log(x)}{c-\log(x)+dx^2\log(x)}$

Tags: asymptotics

In computing an asymptotic expansion I have come across the term:
$$\frac{a+bx^2\log(x)}{c-\log(x)+dx^2\log(x)},$$ 
where $a,b,c$ and $d$ are non zero constants, in general.

I am unsure if to proceed to expand, using the geometric series expansion 
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\log(x)}}=1-\frac{1}{\log(x)}+\frac{1}{\log(x)^2}-\frac{1}{\log(x)^3}+\dots$$ 
or leave this term as is!

I guess in essence I'm asking if $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(x)+1}$ is a 'better' form than $1-\frac{1}{\log(x)}+\frac{1}{\log(x)^2}-\frac{1}{\log(x)^3}+\dots$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not $+ + + + ...$, but $+ -  +  - ...$

Comment: Corrected.. Any other thoughts?